# XAML equivalent of the HTML Title Attribute

Tags: c#, html, xaml

I am developing a small C# WPF application and I would like to know if there is any equivalent of the html title attribute in xaml so that when the mouse is hovering over a button or an element it displays a short text to help the user know what that button does?

If it doesn't exist, then how can I implement it?

Comment: Are you talking about a tooltip?  Each wpf object will have a `tooltip` property you can populate with the text.  That will be visible on mouse over.

Comment: Yes, I'm not native english, so I didn't know where to search

Comment: Downvoter care to explain ?

Comment: I think that takes care of the downvoters. lol.

Comment: The MSDN documentation for any WPF control would have been a good place to start looking.

Comment: I've looked here, but I couldn't find it since I had no idea what it was

Comment: Beginner programmers, especially those whose native language is *not* English, may have trouble finding the right documentation. How about we stop mindlessly downvoting because it's a 'n00b' question, and instead upvote because it helps you learn. I follow the C# tag because I want to learn more about the language and tools that work with it. So boo to downvoters. +1 to OP!

Comment: Thanks, in fact that's because of this kind of behavior that I'm always affraid to ask a question here, I've searched for title in MSDN and Google but when I even don't know that the word tooltip exists, how could you expect me to find anything, and sure it helps, if I didn't ask I would still be searching for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tooltips do exist.  Here is an example of a complex tooltip.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left">TextBox with ToolTip
  <TextBox.ToolTip>
    <TextBlock>Useful information goes here.</TextBlock>
  </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

Taken from [ToolTip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx).

A simple text tooltip can be done like this:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         ToolTip="Useful information goes here.">TextBox with ToolTip</TextBox>
```

This should work for virtually any WPF control.